# Is there a way to find who is the user currently logged in the OS in sqlite3?

Tags: sqlite

For example in DB2 there is a "user" that will give you who is logged in and performing the queries. And no, there is no "logging into DB2" I only login once to gain access to the whole OS (IBM i 7.1).

`declare global temporary table XYZ ( DUMMY char(1))
      Table XYZ created in QTEMP.
insert into XYZ values('1')
      1 rows inserted in XYZ in QTEMP.
select user from XYZ`

Output:

`....+....1....+...
 USER
"my-login-user-id-is-shown-here"
********  End of data  ********`

in sqlite3:

```
SQLite version 3.11.1 2016-03-03 16:17:53
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create temporary table XYZ (DUMMY char(1));
sqlite> insert into XYZ values('1')
   ...> ;
sqlite> select user from XYZ;
Error: no such column: user
sqlite>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a file-based database; it neither cares nor knows about OS users.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this (running sqlite from the unix shell) and found it to be an acceptable solution, but I will like to be able to do the same from within the sqlite command shell.

```
% sqlite3 test.db "select * from NADA where UZER='$USER';"
-- Loading resources from /home/<my-userid>/.sqliterc

UZER                DINERO    
----------              ----------
<my-userid>      117.41
```